# How to get records with rank between 5 and 10

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

I have an employee table with 20 records. The columns are employee name and salary. How can I get the details of employees with ranks between 5 and 10 on the basis of decreasing order of their salaries?

I am thinking of passing the table through a sorter to arrange the data in decreasing order of salaries, and then Sequence Generator Transformation giving unique id to the rows and finally a filter to select where the id is between 5 and 10.
I realise this isn't an elegant solution? Is there a better way to do this? Thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

You can use rank transformation to get the top 10 salaried persons. Then you can filter out the first 5 using the rankindex column